# Unable to load desktop screen after entering my password

Tags: release-loki, desktop

I'm currently using loki elementary and its running very smoothly but yesterday I updated a OS update from app center after that when I restart my system and when enter my password a black screen comes and after that again my login screen appears and every time this happens and I'm unable to open my desktop screen.

[image: this message is appear after entering the password and then the login screen appear again]

This message is appear after entering the password and then the login screen appear again

Comment: This is a very specific question that would require some back-and-forth to troubleshoot. I would suggest submitting a bug report instead. Hopefully the devs (who will know what kind of OS updates shipped in the past few days) can point you to the right place to report it.

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem is removed by updating my elementary os by
**sudo apt update**
**sudo apt full-upgrade**

Answer (score -1):

I just applied the update and have the same problem.
I was able to enter terminal mode by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1`.
I ran the full upgrade; it didn't change anything the first time,
but I rebooted and did the update and full upgrade again, and it worked!

Comment: update and reset your system may remove your problem